# Django with False sending error message through email 10 times on a single error

Tags: django

Here is the code:
server_error function in core url.

```
def server_error(request):
    """
    Custom error handler for reporting errors to the superuser via email and sending the detailed error response.
    """
    if request.method in ('GET', 'POST'):
        subject = f"Error on {request.get_host()}"
        user = request.user if request.user.is_authenticated else None

        # Include username and user ID in the subject if the user exists
        if user:
            subject += f" - User: {user.username} (ID: {user.id})"

        # Generate the detailed error response
        response = technical_500_response(request, *sys.exc_info(), status_code=500)

        # Capture the HTML content
        html_content = response.content.decode('utf-8')

        # Send the email with the error details
        email = EmailMessage(subject, body=html_content, from_email='noreply@questionsbank.net', to=[settings.DEBUG_EMAIL])

        # Set the content type to HTML
        email.content_subtype = 'html'

        # Send the email
        email.send()
        error_email_sent = True
    # Raise an exception to trigger the error handling (optional)
    raise Exception("Server Error")

handler500 = 'project.urls.server_error'
```

fake_error_view which is set to http://127.0.0.1:8000/fake-error/

```
def fake_error_view(request):
    raise ValueError("This is a fake error!")
```

If debug is turned True, it shows one error page on the browser; when debug mode it turned False, I receive the same error through email, where the same email is sent 10 times instead of once.

Can anyone help me understand the issue?